# Drag and Drop To Columns with highlighted dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I search for Drag And Drop To Columns script and i found this one

```
http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?showDownload=true&whichScript=drag_drop_nodes
```

I try to add highlighted color on the items which i move

I add **css** code

```
<style type="text/css">
.highlight {
    background-color: #fff34d;
}
</style>
```

and  modify this in **JavaScript**

```
    function initDragDropScript() {
        dragContentObj = document.getElementById('dragContent');
        dragDropIndicator = document.getElementById('dragDropIndicator');
        dragDropTopContainer = document.getElementById('dhtmlgoodies_dragDropContainer');
        document.documentElement.onselectstart = cancelEvent;;
        var listItems = dragDropTopContainer.getElementsByTagName('LI'); // Get array containing all <LI>
        listItems.className = 'highlight';
        var itemHeight = false;
        for (var no = 0; no < listItems.length; no++) {
            listItems[no].onmousedown = initDrag;
            listItems[no].onselectstart = cancelEvent;
            if (!itemHeight) itemHeight = listItems[no].offsetHeight;
            if (MSIE && navigatorVersion / 1 < 6) {
                listItems[no].style.cursor = 'hand';
            }
        }
        var mainContainer = document.getElementById('dhtmlgoodies_mainContainer');
        var uls = mainContainer.getElementsByTagName('UL');
        itemHeight = itemHeight + verticalSpaceBetweenListItems;
        for (var no = 0; no < uls.length; no++) {
            uls[no].style.height = '480 px';
        }

        var leftContainer = document.getElementById('dhtmlgoodies_listOfItems');
        var itemBox = leftContainer.getElementsByTagName('UL')[0];
        document.documentElement.onmousemove = moveDragContent; // Mouse move event - moving draggable div 
        document.documentElement.onmouseup = dragDropEnd; // Mouse move event - moving draggable div 
        var ulArray = dragDropTopContainer.getElementsByTagName('UL');
        for (var no = 0; no < ulArray.length; no++) {
            ulPositionArray[no] = new Array();
            ulPositionArray[no]['left'] = getLeftPos(ulArray[no]);
            ulPositionArray[no]['top'] = getTopPos(ulArray[no]);
            ulPositionArray[no]['width'] = ulArray[no].offsetWidth;
            ulPositionArray[no]['height'] = ulArray[no].clientHeight;
            ulPositionArray[no]['obj'] = ulArray[no];
        }

        if (!indicateDestionationByUseOfArrow) {
            indicateDestinationBox = document.createElement('LI');
            indicateDestinationBox.id = 'indicateDestination';
            indicateDestinationBox.style.display = 'none';
            document.body.appendChild(indicateDestinationBox);
        }
    }
```

but it is not working any suggestions

Comment: What does your code look like apart from the bit you have included in your question?

Comment: i update the JavaScript code

Comment: do you want to highlight just the one you're dragging or all the ones that have been dropped? Also it may be best for you to use one of the most popular drag and drop plugins http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Comment: yes i want to highlight all the ones that have been dropped, i think this script is powerful more then yours for many items to drag and drop.
ANY AIDES ??